# Context-free Grammar introducting more conditions

Tags: math, context-free-grammar

i need to write a cfg for the language A = {a^i b^j c^k |   i,j,k>0   j!=k}

my first idea was to create a simple grammar without the j!=k restriction

```
S -> A B C
A -> aA | a
B -> bB | b
C -> cC | c
```

this obviously does not work with the restriction, how do i introduce the j!=k to create a new CFG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split it into two cases, depending on whether j>k or k>j.

```
S -> A X | A Y
A -> aA | a
X -> bX | bZ  # every X -> bX gives you an extra b
Y -> Yc | Zc  # every Y -> Yc gives you an extra c
Z -> bZc | bc  # Z produces b^j c^j strings
```

Comment: Thanks, i understand now, you have to split the grammar into the two different cases!